# Nested for-loop and arrays in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

I have an input file which is comma separated lines, which I need to assign to the keys as mentioned below, I have tried assigning them but I'm not able to figure out how to assign them separately yet group together as shown below expected result.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this, I have not used the arrays or comma separated  values before and having issue to get it to work.

**Input file**

```
10.219.196.0,15gb,Azure Cloud
10.219.196.0,55gb,Google Cloud
10.219.196.0,54gb,AWS Cloud
```

I have to assign the IP address with key IP, size with key size and the cloud name with key platform, the tricky part is I have to assign it this way

**Expected Result**

```
IP1=10.219.196.0
Size1=15gb
Platform1=Azure Cloud
IP2=10.219.196.0
Size2=15gb
Platform2=Google Cloud
IP3=10.219.196.0
Size3=15gb
Platform3=AWS Cloud
```

Solution I have tried is as below

```
i=1;
for $line in `cat file`
 do 
    my_ary=$line
    echo "IP$i=${my_ary[0]}"\n
    echo "Size$i=${my_ary[1]}"\n
    echo "platform$i=${my_ary[2]}"\n
    $i++
 done
```

Please let me know how can I fix this to get the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable in `for` must be used without the dollar sign.

Instead of looping over `cat`, you can read the file directly into the array using `read -a`. Setting `$IFS` splits each line on commas.

For increment, use an arithmetic expression `((...))`.

`echo` adds a newline after printing its arguments. No need to write `\n`.

```sh
#! /bin/bash
i=1
while IFS=, read -a my_ary ; do 
    echo "IP$i=${my_ary[0]}"
    echo "Size$i=${my_ary[1]}"
    echo "Platform$i=${my_ary[2]}"
    ((i++))
done < "$1"
```

Comment: thanks for quick response. I actually don't have an input file I'm getting those lines from the sed output, how can I feed the input lines one at a time to this above code ?

Comment: Just remove the `< "$1"`.

Comment: I think, I'm doing something wrong if I just use the input file do I have to pass the path somewhere in the above code ? as I see this stack-answer.sh: 3: stack-answer.sh: cannot open : No such file

Comment: and If I add the file name in place of "$1" I get stack-answer.sh: 3: read: Illegal option -a

Comment: How do you run the script?

Comment: I just run like this sh scriptname

Comment: `sh` is not always `bash`. It's quote possible your `sh` doesn't support arrays at all.

Comment: ok, do you suggest any other way to achieve this without using arrays ?

Comment: No, I suggest to run the script in bash instead of sh.